# Spring security cross browser autologin 

Tags: spring-security

I have 2 web applications running under 2 tomcats. Both these applications use the same UserDetailsService for authentication and same database. I am kinda of confused on how would I be able to autologin the user to the other application running in the same browser or cross browser once he has authenticated himself in one of the application.

Will this help ?

```
<session-management session-fixation-protection="none">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="2" />
</session-management>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet posted above will not work.  All it tells spring security is to allow two sessions for the specified user at a time.

What you need is a [single sign on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) for both the applications.  You may want to explore spring security's [CAS](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/cas.html) support.

Comment: Thanks Raghu ! On implementing CAS will it automatically login to other system or do I have to implement custom filter to do that ?